# How to get the tab bar height in a Xamarin.Forms page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm displaying an image within my content pages such that its height is a fixed percentage of the page height. I do this using a grid with star unit row height. However, when the content pages are placed within a TabbedPage, the total grid height seems to be that of [the screen minus the tab bar height], so as a consequence, the image appears a bit shorter.

If I could access the tab bar height within my content pages, it would be a simple adjustment to the percentage.

Question:

1) How do I get the tab bar height within a content page?

2) Is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) How do I get the tab bar height within a content page?

We can't get tabbar height from PCL directly.Just need a custom renderers for `TabbedRenderer`

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), 
typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.iOS
{
    class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
            App.TabHeight = (int)TabBar.Frame.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

Define `TabHeight` in `App` in PCL

```
public static int TabHeight { get; set; }
```

Get the height in `TabbedPage`

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    int height = App.TabHeight;
}
```

[image]

> 2) Is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

We'r better not set the fixed frame on Image, and should not operate the frame manually .

`Aspect` of `Image` can help us to show the image as we want.

---

#### AspectFit

[image]

---

#### AspectFill

[image]

---

#### Fill

[image]

Comment: Heh, cute dog. I'm already using AspectFill on the image. That's working fine. It's the container the image sits in whose height I need to be a percentage of the entire screen.

Comment: I'll need to try this to see if it works first. I.e, I'll need to set my image container's height by adjusting the percentage based on the tab bar height I get using this method. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

I would suggest you to get the screen size and calculate the percentage based on screen size and use the variable value instead of proportional value, in this way, you could use other the layout other than AbsoluteLayout, but I am using AbsoluteLayout for my example:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            var imageWidth = this.Width;
            var imageHeight = this.Height * 0.25;
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight));
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(image, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);
        }
```

> *** In my test, when I used AbsoluteLayout proportional method
>
> `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds = "0,0,1,0.25"
>   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"`
>
> the outcome of both image size will have
>   slightly different If the page use with or without `Tabbedpage`
>
> So I suggest to use code behind to get the image size based on the [screen height * percentage].

**TabbedPage**

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AbsoluteLayoutExample" x:Class="AbsoluteLayoutExample.AbsoluteLayoutExamplePage">

    <ContentPage x:Name="MyPage" Title = "Page 1">
        <AbsoluteLayout> 
           <Image x:Name="image" Source="icon.png" Aspect="AspectFill" />
        </AbsoluteLayout> 
    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage Title = "Page 2">
        <Label Text="Hello" />
    </ContentPage>

</TabbedPage>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    var imageWidth = this.Width;
    var imageHeight = this.Height * 0.25;
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(image, new Rectangle(0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight));
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(image,AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);
}
```

**Content Page only:**

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage Padding="0,20,0,0"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContentPageWidthAndHieght" 
    x:Class="ContentPageWidthAndHieght.ContentPageWidthAndHieghtPage">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
         <Image x:Name="image" Source="icon.png" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    var imageWidth = this.Width;
    var imageHeight = this.Height * 0.25;
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight));
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(image, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);
}
```

[image]

Comment: The 0.5s in your example...which corner of the Aqua box do they refer to? Also, my original problem is making the height 25% of the screen height, and 100% width. So according to what you are saying, would I need to specify LayoutBounds to be "...100, 25" and LayoutFlags="all"?

Comment: From your question, I think what you really need is not the Tabbed height but when there is a Tab, your image will still remain at the position it should be, am I right?

Comment: Top Left corner is the reference point. Yes,you can use LayoutFlags = “All” but the if 100% and 25% LayoutBounds should be "x,x, 1, 0.25". What is your target image location?

Comment: I have edited my answer, I put the image at the bottom of the screen and it should be similar with your situation.

Comment: My question wasn't to do with the location of my image but its height. The container in which it resides is always at the top but i need this container's height to always be 25 of screen height.

Comment: Which mean with or without tab, the image height need to be  same size? For example without tab, 25% of the height is 100mm and with tab, it also need to be 100mm?