# Xamarin.Forms.Shell: how to get the bottom TabBar height?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, height, tabbar

I work on a **Xamarin.Forms.Shell** app using the default bottom `TabBar`, and I need to know the `TabBar` **height** to adjust some items.

I've found a way to get the `StatusBar` **height** on both platforms [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276053/how-can-i-get-status-bar-height-in-xamarin-forms), but I didn't found a solution for the `TabBar`.

Is it possible? I only found requests about changing the TabBar height on Stack...

Comment: Does it work now ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could  get the height by using **Custom Renderer**

#### in AppShell

```
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
   public static double TabHeight { get; set; }

  //...
}
```

#### in iOS project

**Option 1:**

```
using App33;
using App33.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(ShellCustomRenderer))]
namespace App33.iOS
{
    public class ShellCustomRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
        {
            return new TabBarAppearance();
        }

    }

    public class TabBarAppearance : IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public void ResetAppearance(UITabBarController controller)
        {
            


        }

        public void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            UITabBar myTabBar = this.TabBarController.TabBar;

            myTabBar.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
            myTabBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.LightGray;
            //... you can set style like above in iOS

            AppShell.TabHeight  = myTabBar.Bounds.Height;

        }

        public void UpdateLayout(UITabBarController controller)
        {
           
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

Actually, The height of **UITabbar** on iOS is a fixed value . On iPhone 8 and before is 49 and iPhone X and after(full-screen) will have an extra safeArea bottom height . So if you just want to get it (don't need to set the height) , you could get it directly by using **DependencyService**  like following

```
AppShell.TabHeight = 49 + UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().SafeAreaInsets.Bottom;
```

#### in Android

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //        var hei=SupportActionBar.Height;
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());


            int resourceId =Resources.GetIdentifier("design_bottom_navigation_height", "dimen", this.PackageName);
            int height = 0;
            if (resourceId > 0)
            {
                height = Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
                AppShell.TabHeight = height;
            }

         


        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lucas. It seems to work on **iOS**, but I lose the style specified in **Shell.xaml** for the `TabBar`'s text color. On **Android**, the height is not recovered until I change tab at least one time. As I need this information on the HomePage, I can't use this solution. In add, I also lose the default style.

Comment: You could re-set the style after get the height .

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, in **Xamarin.Forms** it is not (yet?) possible to retrieve the `TabBar` `Height`, so you might have to go and collect that information per **Platform**. Then, making use of `DependencyService` you would be able to make that information available from your **Xamarin.Forms** shared code. So, lets take a look at how to do it:

### iOS

For **iOS**, there have already been published answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47709804/7432242) to explain how this can be done.

### Android

For **Android** you can retrieve the TabBar height as follows

- Create **Interface** for Dependency

Note: This interface should also be used on the iOS part ;)

```
namespace Tabbarheight
{
    public interface IDisplayHeights
    {
        float GetTabBarHeight();
    }
}
```

- Create a class in **Android** that implements that interface and returns the desired value

(thanks to @LucasZhang-MSFT for the identifier string!)

```
using Android.App;
using Tabbarheight.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AndroidDisplayHeights))]
namespace Tabbarheight.Droid
{
    class AndroidDisplayHeights : IDisplayHeights
    {
        public static Activity Activity { get; set; }

        public float GetTabBarHeight()
        {
            int resourceId = Activity.Resources.GetIdentifier("design_bottom_navigation_height", "dimen", Activity.PackageName);
            int height = 0;
            if (resourceId > 0)
            {
                height = (int)(Activity.Resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId) / Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density);
            }

            return height;

        }
    }
}
```

where `Activity` is set from **MainActivity.cs** as follows

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

    AndroidDisplayHeights.Activity = this;

    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

- And finally, you can consume this as follows

```
public AboutPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SizeChanged += (s, a) =>
    {
        label.HeightRequest = DependencyService.Get<IDisplayHeights>().GetTabBarHeight();
        label.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;

    };

}
```

---

In the solution above i defined a `Label` (label) simply to try to demonstrate the accuracy of the gotten `TabBar`'s `Height` value by setting the `Label`'s height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Tabbarheight.Views.AboutPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Tabbarheight.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="label">
            <Label.Text>
                <x:String>
                    Hola mundo
                </x:String>
            </Label.Text>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

The label looks like this on my side:

[image]